# mysql golang - returning blank when querying for table

Tags: mysql, go

```golang
    type reason4 struct {
    reason string
    }


    query := "SELECT reason FROM misc WHERE reason=?"
    var misc reason4
    row1, err := db.Query(query, "1")
    row1.Scan(
        &misc.reason,
    )
    fmt.Println(misc.reason)
```

When I try to print misc.reason it returns blank. Any help would be appreciated - if I missed out on any details please let me know.

Comment: can you show the output of running that query directly in mysql? you should check the `err` variable and the return of `Scan`

Comment: you are missing `row1.Next()` before `Scan`

Comment: No err is returned when checked. However checking Scan showed this.

Comment: @NuLo sql: Rows are closed

Comment: Did you add `row1.Next()` and checked it's return?

Comment: @NuLo sql: Rows are closed

Comment: thats's the return of row1.Next?

Comment: You are not checking the `err` from `Query`. You are not calling `Next()` before `Scan`. You are not checking the error returned by `Scan`. You are not closing the rows properly. And so on... To query multiple rows you should do follow the example [here](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#example-Rows). To query only a single row you should instead follow the example [here](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#example-DB.QueryRowContext).